# Changing the font size of the global navigation in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-navigation, global-navigation

I have a navbar at the top of my SharePoint Online sites. Each site has the same navigation structure, achieved using `terms`. However, the size of the text is annoyingly small given that it functions as the only inter-site navigation menu.

[image: Screenshot showing the small navbar]

I can write the CSS to modify these quite easily, but I'd be happy to apply a different "Look and Feel" template, but none of the templates provided affect the navbar.

My questions are:

- How can I apply this CSS in **SharePoint Online** (rather than SharePoint on-prem)?
- Is it possible to apply the same styling across many sites with the CSS referenced in one place?

I am designing these sites by clicking "Create Site" and using the in-browser editor, rather than using SharePoint Designer.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can inject Custom CSS on SharePoint Modern Pages using SPFx Extensions.

The source code from GitHub: [Spfx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)

Refer to the blog here: [Inject Custom CSS on SharePoint Modern Pages using SPFx Extensions](http://Inject%20Custom%20CSS%20on%20SharePoint%20Modern%20Pages%20using%20SPFx%20Extensions)